# multiple messages through the same socket doesn't work

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, ftp, ftp-server

Im working on a simple ftp server, and the client must send multiples messages to the server, and for each message the server send back to the client a anwser. when the client sends one message it works perfectly and the server responds without any problem, for example, when the client sends "USER username" the server send back to the client "password needed".

But when the client sends another message "PASS password" (using the same socket) it doesnt work ! ONLY the first exchange works (for the username), when the first message is sent, the server anwser without any problem, but it block when it want to send the second message (for the password).

please anyone can help me ? thank you !!

here is my code :

```
 @Test
public void testProcessPASS() throws IOException{

    Socket socket = new Socket(server.getAddress(), server.getcmdPort());

    this.ClientReceiveMessage(socket); // to flush
    String cmd = "USER user_test\r\n";
    this.ClientSendMessage(socket, cmd);
    String anwser = this.ClientReceiveMessage(socket); 
    assertEquals("Response error.", Constants.MSG_331.replace("\r\n", ""), anwser);

    //PROBLEME STARTS HERE :/

    String cmd2 = "PASS pass_test\r\n";
    this.ClientSendMessage(socket, cmd2);
    String anwser2 = this.ClientReceiveMessage(socket); 
    assertEquals(Constants.MSG_230.replace("\r\n", ""), anwser2);
    socket.close();

}


public void ClientSendMessage(Socket skt, String msg) throws IOException{

    PrintWriter messageClient = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(skt.getOutputStream()),true);
    messageClient.println(msg);
    messageClient.flush();

}

public String ClientReceiveMessage(Socket skt) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));
    String res = br.readLine() ;
    return res; 
}
```

this is the server code :

```
 public class Server implements Runnable {

private ServerSocket cmdserverSocket;
private ServerSocket dataServerSocket;

private boolean running;

public Server() throws IOException {
    this.cmdserverSocket = new ServerSocket(1024);
    this.dataServerSocket = new ServerSocket(1025);
    this.running = false;
}

public boolean isRunning() {
    return this.running;
}

public InetAddress getAddress() {
    return this.cmdserverSocket.getInetAddress();
}

public int getcmdPort() {
    return this.cmdserverSocket.getLocalPort();
}

public int getDataPort() {
    return this.dataServerSocket.getLocalPort();
}

public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.running = true;
    System.out.println("server started on port : " + this.getcmdPort());

    while (this.running) {
        try {
            Socket socket = this.cmdserverSocket.accept();
            new Thread(new FtpRequest(socket, this.dataServerSocket))
                    .start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("server error : " + e.getMessage());
            this.running = false;
        }
    }
}

}
```

and this is the class that handles client requests and that sends messages to client and running on a new thread :

```
 public class FtpRequest implements Runnable {

private Socket cmdSocket;
private Socket dataSocket;
private BufferedReader cmdBufferedReader;
private DataOutputStream cmdDataOutputStream;
private ServerSocket dataServerSocket;
private boolean anonymous;
private boolean connected;
private String username;
private boolean processRunning;
private String directory;

public FtpRequest(Socket cmds, ServerSocket dts) throws IOException {

    this.cmdSocket = cmds;
    this.dataServerSocket = dts;
    this.cmdBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            this.cmdSocket.getInputStream()));
    this.cmdDataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
            this.cmdSocket.getOutputStream());
    this.anonymous = true;
    this.connected = false;
    this.username = Constants.ANONYMOUS_USER;
    this.processRunning = true;
    this.directory = "/home";

}

/**
 * send a message on the socket of commands
 * 
 * @param msg
 *            the msg to send on the socket of commands
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void sendMessage(String msg) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("FtpRequest sendMessage : " + msg);
    PrintWriter messageClient = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            this.cmdDataOutputStream), true);
    messageClient.println(msg);
    messageClient.flush();

    /*
     * this.cmdDataOutputStream.writeBytes(msg);
     * this.cmdDataOutputStream.flush(); this.cmdSocket.close();
     */
}

public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("FtpRequest running ...");
    try {
        this.sendMessage(Constants.MSG_220); // service ready for new user
        this.handleRequest();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // service ready for new user

}

/**
 * this method handle the request readen from cmd socket and run the
 * required method
 * 
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void handleRequest() throws IOException {

    String rqst = this.cmdBufferedReader.readLine();

    Request request = new Request(rqst);
    System.out.println("FtpRequest handleRequest" + rqst);

    switch (request.getType()) {
    case USER:
        this.processUSER(request);
        break;

    case PASS:
        this.processPASS(request);
        break;

    default:
        this.sendMessage(Constants.MSG_502); // Command not implemented.\r\n
        break;

    }

    /*
     * if (this.processRunning = true) this.handleRequest();
     * 
     * else { this.cmdSocket.close(); System.out.println("socket closed ");
     * }
     */

}

private void processUSER(Request rqst) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("FtpRequest processUSER");
    if (rqst.getArgument().equals(Constants.ANONYMOUS_USER)) {
        this.sendMessage(Constants.MSG_230); // user loged in
        this.connected = true;
        this.anonymous = true;
        this.username = Constants.ANONYMOUS_USER;
    } else if (rqst.getArgument().equals(Constants.USER_TEST)) {
        this.sendMessage(Constants.MSG_331); // User name okay, need
                                                // password.\r\n
        this.username = Constants.USER_TEST;
    } else
        this.sendMessage(Constants.MSG_332);
}

private void processPASS(Request rqst) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("FtpRequest processPASS");
    if (rqst.getArgument().equals(Constants.USER_TEST)
            && rqst.getArgument().equals(Constants.PASS_TEST)) {
        this.sendMessage(Constants.MSG_230);
        this.connected = true;
        this.anonymous = false;
    } else
        this.sendMessage(Constants.MSG_332); // au cas seulement le mot de
                                                // passe est fourni
}


}
```

Comment: @Remy Lebeau thank you :) what should I do for multi-line responses ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems with your code.

`ClientSendMessage()` is using `PrintWriter.println()`, which outputs a line break.  But your input strings *already* have line breaks on them, so the `println()` is sending extra line breaks.  Also, the line break `println()` outputs is platform-dependent, whereas FTP uses `CRLF` specifically.  So you should not be using `println()` at all.

`ClientReceiveMessage()` does not account for multi-line responses.   Per [RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959), section 4.2 "FTP REPLIES":

```
A reply is defined to contain the 3-digit code, followed by Space
<SP>, followed by one line of text (where some maximum line length
has been specified), and terminated by the Telnet end-of-line
code.  There will be cases however, where the text is longer than
a single line.  In these cases the complete text must be bracketed
so the User-process knows when it may stop reading the reply (i.e.
stop processing input on the control connection) and go do other
things.  This requires a special format on the first line to
indicate that more than one line is coming, and another on the
last line to designate it as the last.  At least one of these must
contain the appropriate reply code to indicate the state of the
transaction.  To satisfy all factions, it was decided that both
the first and last line codes should be the same.

   Thus the format for multi-line replies is that the first line
   will begin with the exact required reply code, followed
   immediately by a Hyphen, "-" (also known as Minus), followed by
   text.  The last line will begin with the same code, followed
   immediately by Space <SP>, optionally some text, and the Telnet
   end-of-line code.

      For example:
                          123-First line
                          Second line
                            234 A line beginning with numbers
                          123 The last line

   The user-process then simply needs to search for the second
   occurrence of the same reply code, followed by <SP> (Space), at
   the beginning of a line, and ignore all intermediary lines.  If
   an intermediary line begins with a 3-digit number, the Server
   must pad the front to avoid confusion.
```

The server's initial greeting is likely to be multi-line, but any response to any command can potentially be multi-line, so you need to handle that.

But more importantly, when doing error checking, you need to look at **only** the 3-digit response code, **not** the text that accompanies it.  Except for a few select commands, like `PASV`, `MLST`/`MLSD`, etc, the text is otherwise *arbitrary*, the server can send whatever it wants.  So you need to ignore the text except for those cases where it is actually needed, or when reporting error messages to the user.

Try something more like this:

```
private Socket socket;
private BufferedReader br;

 @Test
public void testProcessPASS() throws IOException{    

    socket = new Socket(server.getAddress(), server.getcmdPort());
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    this.ClientReceiveMessage(220);
    this.ClientSendMessage("USER user_test", 331);
    this.ClientSendMessage("PASS pass_test", 230);
    this.ClientSendMessage("QUIT", 221);

    socket.close();

    br = null;
    socket = null;
}

public int ClientSendMessage(String msg, int ExpectedReplyCode) throws IOException{

    Writer bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
    bw.write(msg);
    bw.write("\r\n");
    bw.flush();

    return ClientReceiveMessage(ExpectedReplyCode);
}

public int ClientReceiveMessage(int ExpectedReplyCode) throws IOException{

    String line = br.readLine();
    String msgText = msgText.substring(4);

    if ((line.length() >= 4) && (line[3] == '-')) {
        String endStr = line.substring(0, 2) + " ";
        do {
            line = br.readLine();
            msgText += ("\r\n" + line.substring(4));
        }
        while (line.substring(0, 3) != endStr);
    }

    int actualReplyCode = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2));
    assertEquals("Response error. " + msgText, ExpectedReplyCode, actualReplyCode);

    // TODO: if the caller wants the msgText for any reason,
    // figure out a way to pass it back here...

    return actualReplyCode;
}
```

Comment: it reads one line at a time, but for each line it corresponds to a response of the server, am I wrong ?

Comment: @AymaneBo: yes, you are wrong.  Sometimes a single response can have **more than one** line in it.  FTP defines a very specific format to detect this situation so you know when to stop reading.

Comment: You must use the same `BufferedReader` for the life of the socket, and having done that you may as well use the same `PrintWriter` as well.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau actually my ftp server is meant to be really simple, its for university class, so the servers replies are always only one line. I tried your solution but still the same problem :/

Comment: even if that is true, you should still compare only the response codes, not the full text. Did you make that change yet? Also, the `PrintWriter.println()` is a problem, did you remove that yet? Are you using the latest code update from my answer?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is even on the client to side to begin, and not on the server side? What does the server code look like?

Comment: yes I copy pasted the solution :/ Im going to update the question so you can see the server side, thank you !

Comment: @RemyLebeau your solution is actually working Remy !! I just removed this line : bw.write("\r\n");  from the clientSendMessage() method. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: @AymaneBo if you look closely, I had added `bw.write("\r\n")` because I had removed `'"\r\n"` from the input strings. This ensures consistency and makes the commands easier to read.